# Can't get notify in postgresql trigger function to work

Tags: postgresql-9.1

Running *Postgresql 9.1* on *ubuntu*.
I have a database defined and it has a table named **pending**.
I created a trigger function named **ins_notify_function**.
The content of this function is

```
    BEGIN
    NOTIFY "inspend", 'fired by NOTIFY';
    RETURN NULL;
    END
```

I have a trigger function created:

```
   CREATE TRIGGER audit_ins
   AFTER INSERT
   ON pending
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE ins_notify_function();
```

So, I then run *psql* and type into it:

```
   LISTEN "inspend";
```

In *psql* I type:

```
   NOTIFY "inspend";
```

and get back the Asynchronous notification ...
message.

Insert a record in the table pending and *psql* does NOT show Asynchronous notification ...
It shows nothing.

Am I missing a step here?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks reasonable, at a glance should work. Show the *full* function definition, your PostgreSQL version, and the actual output from `psql` when you do the `insert`.

Comment: That is the full function.  I just have the notify and return statement.   My PostgreSQL version is 9.1.7.   I did the insert from pgadmin III's sql editor.  The records are successfully entered as I can see them later in view data.

Comment: Any chance you can supply a complete .SQL file + instructions to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Well, did more testing this AM.   If I do the insert from psql then the trigger works as expected.  If I do the insert from PGADMIN III, I get nothing.  Is this operating as designed ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I wound out that I was in stransaction. NOTIFY events are not fired while in transaction.